# How to get max value from the file

Tags: vb.net

I'm coding the high score panel for a game I've made.

The code writes all the scores to a text file and then reads them, finds the highest score and display it in a text box.
I have the issue that the largest value that displayed is never over 9.

This is the code that I've written to read the text file and write the largest value to a Label

```
Dim fileReader As String
fileReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("C:\Users\samdo_000\Desktop\1234\score.txt")
topScore.Text = (fileReader.Max)
```

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks

```
scorePnl.Show()
Dim file As System.IO.StreamWriter
file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("C:\Users\samdo_000\Desktop\1234\score.txt", True)
file.WriteLine(pipeNumber)
file.Close()
Dim fileReader As String
fileReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("C:\Users\samdo_000\Desktop\1234\score.txt")
topScore.Text = (fileReader.Max)
currentScore.Text = pipeNumber
Timer1.Enabled = False
```

Everytime the game ends it stores an integer (pipeNumber)

Comment: Assuming "read all text" returns single "word", all you need is `topScore.Text = fileReader`. To say more we need to know how you store the data. Although, I am afraid, you need "read all lines" to get string array, and then you can use `Enumerable.select` to convert to integers and get `max`

Comment: please don't use comment area for code - you need to add the code to the question - edit your question

Comment: instead of `Dim lines As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText` you need  `Dim lines() As String = File.ReadAllLines`. NOTE: `lines` - single value; `lines()` - array. Also, you mixing `ReadAllText` and `ReadAllLines`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have bunch of lines and each contains a numeric value, this will do it

```
dim lines() as string = File.ReadAllLines("C:\Users\samdo_000\Desktop\1234\score.txt")
dim max as Long = lines.Select(function (i as Long)i).Max()
txt.Text = max
```

Comment: Long?  How big of scores are you expecting the game to use?  :-)

Comment: @LarsTech I just got a buzzilion in minesweeper

Comment: @SamDowrick This works, your code is not correct. Pay attention to details

Answer (score 1):

`fileReader.Max` is returning the highest valued character it can find in your string, which is probably just 9.

Assuming the text file has every score separated by a line break, you would probably just loop through each line and test to make sure your "string" is actually a score, and if so, test for the highest value:

```
Dim highScore As Integer = 0
For Each s As String In File.ReadAllLines("C:\Users\samdo_000\Desktop\1234\score.txt")
  Dim testScore As Integer
  If Integer.TryParse(s, testScore) Then
    highScore = Math.Max(highScore, testScore)
  End If
Next
topScore.Text = highScore.ToString
```

Answer (score 0):

`My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText` returns a `String`, which is an `IEnumerable(Of Char)`.

The `.Max()` method is an extension to The `IEnumerable(Of Char)` - basically trading the string as an array of characters.  So by using the `.Max()` method you are really asking for the largest single character, which amongst an array of arabic numerals will top out at "9".

You need to transform your character array into an integer array of some kind.

Assuming your file is record delimited by carriage-return/line-feed (`VbCrLf`), one method you could use would be:

```
Dim lines As List(Of String) = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(path).Split({vbCr, vbLf}, SplitOptions.RemoveEmpty)
Dim items As List(Of Int64) = New List(Of Int64)

lines.Each(Sub(i) items.Add(Int64.Parse(i)))

Dim maxScore As Int64 = items.Max()
```

Code here is untested.  There may be spelling/syntax errors.  It's only presented as a starting point.

A much better option would be to use serialization.  You should definitely read up on it.  The Newtonsoft.Json serializer available from NuGet would work great - as would `System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer`.